# CakePHP 2.2 403 error upon installation with Apache

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

So I downloaded the latest version of CakePHP verbatim and unzipped it into the directory `/var/www/cake_2/` (Apache2 on Ubuntu). When I try to access `localhost/cake/`, I get the following error:

`You don't have permission to access /cake/ on this server.`

This seems to be a similar problem:
https://serverfault.com/questions/70243/mod-rewrite-cakephp-routing-functionality-forbidden-after-snow-leopard-upgrade

I have added:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and changed the contents of .htaccess in `/var/www/cake/` to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and I am still getting the same error. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: Sounds like a permission error. Make sure the `/cake` directory is readable by apache (check the apache conf for the user:group it's using).

Answer (score 8):

check cake/.htaccess , cake/app/webroor/.htaccess are be in folders.

then run these commands in terminal in cake folder:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

first line changes folder permission and the second changes files permission, 
then you must change tmp folder permission to 777.